How to find IPFS multiaddress given a gateway?
I'd like to improve the peering of my IPFS node. Given a public gateway like https://ipfs.io, how can I find it's multiaddress to manually add to my IPFS peering config?
I tried doing
 ❯❯❯ curl https://ipfs.io/api/v0/id
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.27.0</center>
</body>
</html>

but it seems like that was removed in 0.28
EDIT: and what about gateways that have disabled the /api paths like
 ❯❯❯ curl https://hardbin.com/api/v0/id
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)</center>
</body>
</html>

